# flexible Header, scrollable body and footer in HTML

Tags: html, css, layout, height, scrollable

I'm trying to create a simple HTML layout where there is a header, content and footer section vertically layed out.

The heights of both header and footer should be flexible, determined by the content.

The height of the content section should be the remaining height, so the entire layout uses the full height of the window. The content section would be scrollable.

So, in order:

1. Header. Height depends on content height. No scrollbars.
2. Content. Height is the remainder; window_height - (header_height + footer_height). Scrollbar if needed (overflow: auto;)
3. Footer. Height depends on content height. No scrollbars.

There are many examples for static header and footer heights but I found none that can deal with content-based heights.

I've tried plain divs with position: absolute/relative/fixed. I've tried divs with display: table/table-row/table-cell in several configurations. I've even tried using an actual . But none of these seem to work. Here's one of the many failed attempts: http://jsbin.com/uveloj/15/edit

How can I do this without scripting (I prefer not to rely on JS whenever possible), if it is even possible at all.

Comment: the answer is simple: this can't be done CSS only, not if you need flexible height for header and/or footer.

Comment: I also do wish the "float: bottom;" to exist... but it is not the case. Dont know any way of doing this with pure CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using JavaScript I don't think this is possible.  In order to get the middle scroll you desire the content area must have a set height.  If the header and footer can change dynamically there is no way to update the height of the content area to accommodate for scrolling without using JavaScript.  However, this is a pretty simple layout if you want to just write a few lines of JS.  I have a nice example for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/rogerblanton/8ctJJ/

Frames SHOULD NOT be used.

Comment: I'm afraid JS indeed seems to be the only way out. Perhaps I need to rethink the UI layout if I want to avoid using JS for layout.

Comment: perhaps, I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do but using JavaScript for something as easy as this I don't think will hinder any ones user experience.  I've done things like this countless times and I have never noticed any problems. unless you don't want to use it for some other reason.

Comment: The example you gave doesn't seem to handle dynamically changing the height of footer/header. But it was a good starting point for this:
http://jsfiddle.net/AJUCh/

Answer (score 1):

Did you think about using frames?

Comment: The site I'm working on uses javascript-based drag&drop; frames would make that very difficult, if not impossible.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across this thread much later, but found it useful.

I found that in the general case, you need to take into account margins, borders, etc. You can use jQuery's outerHeight() function to help:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();
    var headerHeight = $('div#header').outerHeight(true)
    var footerHeight = $('div#footer').outerHeight(true);

    var contentHeight = windowHeight - ( footerHeight + headerHeight );
    var contentMargins = $('div#content').outerHeight(true) - $('div#content').height();
    var contentInnerHeight = contentHeight - contentMargins;

    $('div#content').height(contentInnerHeight);
}).resize();
```

Besides the js fixing the content's height, the only really important bit is to have the content's overflow style be scroll or auto.

Here's a modified example of Roger's fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nuAmG/1/